# Strange characters in serial monitor

Tags: arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I started seeing strange characters like this...

> got code >���?␟<

...printing out in my serial monitor when using this code...

```
Serial.printf("got code >%s<\n", code);
```

This was despite my unit tests telling me that the (Arduino) `String` code actually contained printable characters (alpha-numerics and simple punctuation).

It wasn't happening for all my printf statements, but would consistently happen with the same ones.

Answer (score 1):

The problem went away when I broke `Serial.printf` into a series of `Serial.print` statements, e.g.

```
Serial.print("got code >");
Serial.print(code);
Serial.println("<");
```

I still haven't figured out why, unfortunately, but I hope this saves you some time.

Comment: What is the data type of `code`? A c-string (I.e. a char array) or an Arduino `String` object?

Comment: @hcheung it's an Arduino String

Comment: `Serial.printf()` formatter `%s` is expecting a char array (i.e. a c-string). To use the Arduino String, the String object need to convert to char array with `Serial.printf("got code >%s<\n", code.c_str());`. I'm surprise that you didn't get a compiler error or warning.